# How to combine two queries calculating maximum in a single report

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

I have a table (`table1`) containing:

Sub_county_name,
county_name, malepop(for each sub county), femalepop(for each sub county)

I want to make a report that gives me the sub counties with the highest male and highest female population  in  their county.

What I've tried:

I have created two queries,one for calculating sub county with highest male pop and one for calculating sub county with highest female pop. However, I am not sure how to combine the two into a single report. Could I get a hint on how to do that?

The queries I have used are:

```
SELECT Sub_county_name,county_name,male_pop
FROM table1
WHERE male_pop = (SELECT MAX(male_pop) FROM table1 a
                  WHERE a.county_name = table1.county_name);


SELECT Sub_county_name,county_name,female_pop
FROM table1
WHERE female_pop = (SELECT MAX(female_pop) FROM table1 a
                    WHERE a.county_name = table1.county_name);
```

Comment: OR the two WHERE clauses together?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to combine the queries , you can get using following query :

```
SELECT        Sub_county_name, county_name, male_pop, female_pop
FROM            table1
WHERE        (male_pop =
                             (SELECT        MAX(male_pop) AS Expr1
                               FROM            table1 AS a
                               WHERE        (county_name = table1.county_name))) AND (female_pop =
                             (SELECT        MAX(female_pop) AS Expr1
                               FROM            table1 AS a
                               WHERE        (county_name = table1.county_name)))
```

Comment: I guess OP wants OR instead of AND.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the subqueries into the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1 JOIN
     (SELECT county_name, MAX(male_pop) as maxmp, MAX(female_pop) as maxfp
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY county_name
     ) m
     ON table1.county_name = m.county_name and
        (table1.male_pop = m.maxmp OR table1.female_pop = m.maxfp);
```